# Javascript Camera toggle not toggling

Tags: javascript, ios, camera, getusermedia

I'm looking to toggle a camera (`facingMode`) from `user` to `environment`. The toggle seems to be working in the sense that `front` is toggling from true to false. However, `facingMode` in `constraints` remains `environment`.

What am I overlooking?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/abenjamin/pen/qYWeXj?editors=1111

```
var front = false;
document.getElementById('cameraToggle').onclick = function() { front = !front; console.log(constraints) };

var constraints = { video: { facingMode: (front? "user" : "environment") } };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeated this line twice in your codepen, once at the top and once at the bottom:

```
document.getElementById('cameraToggle').onclick = function() { front = !front; console.log(constraints) };
```

Another problem is that primitives are referenced by *value*. If you have `let x = 3; const obj = { x }; x = 4;`, the object will not change - it will continue to be `{ x: 3 }`.

What you need to do is update the *constraints object itself* and then proceed to do whatever you need to do with the mutated object. For example:

```
document.getElementById('cameraToggle').onclick = function() {
  front = !front;
  constraints.video.facingMode = front
    ? "user"
    : "environment";
  // interact with the mutated `constraints` object if needed
};
```

Comment: Good catch on the repeat. I implemented a line to have the object update itself, but it seems to only work sometimes. It's really strange. The `front` toggle goes from true/false as it should, but the `facingMode` only switches sometimes and often gets stuck in either `user` or `environment`.